# Why doesn't the address of a float variable and its pointer yield the same result?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float f = 3.2;
    float *fPointer = &f;
    printf("%u\n%u\n", f, fPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

f = 2684354560

fPointer = 1074370969

Aren't they supposed to be the same?

Comment: Ya. Output is same. What do you want? BTW, use `%p` for pointer data types.

Comment: Why *do* they yield the same result, you mean?

Comment: `float f` is a float, but `3,2` is a double.

Comment: You post two identical numbers and ask if they are the same. What's the actual question?

Comment: Sorry! you are right. I corrected the results.

Comment: You are printing `f` as `unsigned` rather than `&f`  The addresses are the same, your code is just not showing the address of `f`.

Comment: I understood my mistake now. Than you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to printf address (pointer value) you forgot to give `&f` to get result do

```
printf("%p\n%p\n", &f, fPointer);
```

If you want printf value then do

```
printf("%f\n%f\n", f, *fPointer);
```

Comment: `%u` expects unsigned int, but there is no `unsigned int`. Use `%p`

Comment: [Why are you saying that](http://pastebin.com/pKtQHPwK)?

Comment: In VS it's not giving any warning and giving correct output.

Comment: I am using codeblocks on windows 7 sp1 machine. 

I think I have used the wrong placeholder symbol as you have stated.

I should have used %p insted of %u.

Comment: @Mohan Use codeblocks if your VS does that. But not your IDE is the only problem when you say that `In VS it's not giving any warning and giving correct output`

Comment: @ Michi I have accepted your suggestion....& updated the answer also...